# How can I keep notes that records my current app?

Tags: ios, note-taking, user-interface, debugging

Often, when I'm using an application, I want to make a quick note about an annoyance or an idea for improving the software.

Usually, if I want to do this, I have to open my note-taking app, text editor, or email program. This process actually causes me to lose focus; not only does it take too much time, but it makes me more prone to distraction.

Is there a software application that will allow me to briefly create/edit a note, but automatically record/reference the software that I was using prior to note-taking?

I know that there are programs like OneNote or DEVONThink that will work with a web browser and associate a note with a web page I might be visiting, but I'd like to extend that to *any* application that I might be using, not just a browser. Bonus points if would also allow me to make screenshots or screen recordings.

Imagine this scenario:

*I'm running a photo-editor program called FooBar2. While I'm using it, I discover a bug. So I activate my FANTASYNOTE software, make some very brief notes about the problem and/or screen grabs for later reference. I resume my work with FooBar2. I then run my SaltyPie database to query some data. While I'm doing that, I think of some interface improvement ideas that I want to share with the SaltyPie software developers. I quickly do that using FANTASYNOTE. Once I'm done with my main work for the day, I pull up FANTASYNOTE, review the notes I took earlier regarding FooBar2 and SaltyPie, which automatically captured the program I was using and maybe some other useful metadata too like version number(s), system info, my network type, etc. In fact, I can see other notes that I took earlier in the week, which helps me identify a pattern that I wouldn't had otherwise noticed. I then share my notes with the developers of the respective programs, and they are most grateful that they have a user that actively helps them improve their software.*

I'd like it to run on iOS and/or macOS. Willing to pay maybe $100 max, depending on how useful the software is.